# Why does Master think it's a Slave on Reboot?

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

In a simple MySQL replication Master-Slave configuration I have a problem where Master tries to connect to itself as a slave on reboot.

So when I restart MySQL on Master, I see errors related to the same server trying to replicate to itself and I have to manually run `mysql -e "STOP SLAVE;"` every time I restart MySQL.

How can I disable slave on master for good?

Here's the relevant portion of `my.cnf`:

```
## Logging
binlog_format                   = mixed
log_bin                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog                     = 1
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#general_log                     = 0
#general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql/general.log
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time                 = 3
expire_logs_days                = 14

sql_mode                        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# sql_mode                        = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

## Replication
server_id                       = 200

## Master Configuration
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_1
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_2
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_3
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_4
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_5
binlog-do-db                    = my_db_6
```

Also, when I run `SELECT * FROM mysql.user;` I don't see the `repl` user that's allegedly a "slave" on Master.

**BUT**, I do see that `localhost` has replication grants:

```
mysql> select Host, User, grant_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv from mysql.user;
+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Host            | User          | grant_priv | Repl_slave_priv | Repl_client_priv |
+-----------------+---------------+------------+-----------------+------------------+
| localhost       | root          | Y          | Y               | Y                |
| localhost       | mysql.sys     | N          | N               | N                |
```

Here's an example of the errors I see on Reboot (before I run `STOP SLAVE;` on Master):

```
2016-09-01T15:22:23.845505Z 384 [Note] Access denied for user 'repl'@'192.168.100.200' (using password: YES)
2016-09-01T15:22:23.845761Z 1 [ERROR] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'repl@192.168.100.200:3306' - retry-time: 30  retries: 8, Error_code: 1045
2016-09-01T15:22:50.191636Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 6843ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=15210 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

Apart from this, replication is running fine. Writes to Master show up flawlessly on the real, read-only, Slave.

---

Full `my.cnf`:

```
[mysql]
default_character_set           = utf8

[mysqld]
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links                  = 0

## Custom Configuration
skip_external_locking           = 1
skip_name_resolve
open_files_limit                = 20000

## Cache
thread_cache_size               = 16
query_cache_type                = 1
query_cache_size                = 256M
query_cache_limit               = 4M

## Per-thread Buffers
sort_buffer_size                = 32M
read_buffer_size                = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size            = 8M
join_buffer_size                = 2M

## Temp Tables
tmp_table_size                  = 1024M
max_heap_table_size             = 1024M

## Networking
back_log                        = 250
max_connections                 = 512
max_connect_errors              = 100000
max_allowed_packet              = 128M
interactive_timeout             = 1800
wait_timeout                    = 1800
character_set_client_handshake  = FALSE
character_set_server            = utf8mb4
collation_server                = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

### Storage Engines
default_storage_engine          = InnoDB
innodb                          = FORCE

## MyISAM
key_buffer_size                 = 128M
myisam_sort_buffer_size         = 16M

## InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 46G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 64
innodb_log_files_in_group       = 2
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 32M
innodb_log_file_size            = 64M
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_thread_concurrency       = 0
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1

## Logging
binlog_format                   = mixed
log_bin                         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog                     = 1
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#general_log                     = 0
#general_log_file                = /var/log/mysql/general.log
slow_query_log                  = 1
slow_query_log_file             = /var/log/mysql/slow.log
long_query_time                 = 3
expire_logs_days                = 14

sql_mode                        = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
# sql_mode                        = ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

## Replication
# Master Server ID:
server_id                       = 200
# Slave Server ID:
# server_id                       = 300

## Master Configuration
# Comment out on Slave
binlog-do-db                    = db_1
binlog-do-db                    = db_2
binlog-do-db                    = db_3
binlog-do-db                    = db_4
binlog-do-db                    = db_5
binlog-do-db                    = db_6

## Slave Configuration
# Uncomment the following on Slave
# relay-log                       = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log
# binlog-do-db                    = db_1
# binlog-do-db                    = db_2
# binlog-do-db                    = db_3
# binlog-do-db                    = db_4
# binlog-do-db                    = db_5
# binlog-do-db                    = db_6
# log_slave_updates               = 1
# read_only                       = 1
# slave_skip_errors               = 1062

[mysqld_safe]
datadir                         = /var/lib/mysql
socket                          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links                  = 0
pid_file                        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
log_error                       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

Also:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%master_info_repository%';
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| master_info_repository | FILE  |
+------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Can you add the full my.cnf?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, yes. I'd welcome any other optimization feedback on `my.cnf` while you're looking at it.

Comment: It does seem a bit odd that I double up on `binlog-do-db`s. Should both Master and Slave have matching `binlog-do-db`s?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, I see that `localhost` has replication grants. Could that be the cause? See updated info above.

Comment: The grants shouldn't matter, they are only used by the replication, but do not trigger the replication. The main problem seems to be the server-id. Set the server-id to 1 please and see if it solves this issue.

Comment: Can you check the variable: master_info_repository: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%master_info_repository%';

Comment: What versions are the two MySQLs?  Are they both on the same server?  If not, why are you asking about `localhost`?  Are you sure the `server_id` values are different?  Is `read_only` being set somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

For managing this kind of setups I recommend to use MHA manager. For this specific situation you may want to clean up the `master_info_repository` (located by default in master.info). Also, you can use `--skip-slave-start` on the master host to avoid this situations after failover.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you must have set the master information on the master server (maybe this was a slave at some point or refreshed from one).  Run

```
SHOW SLAVE STATUS
```

on the master.  If the entries are not all empty then this is the cause and on reboot (without `skip-slave-start` being set) MySQL will try to start the slave.

To fix this, on the master, stop the slave if you did not already and run

```
RESET SLAVE ALL
```

to clear the master settings - assuming that you are using 5.5.16 or higher otherwise leave off the `ALL`.

This can be confirmed with another `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` which should show all the entries as empty.

When you reboot now the slave will not try to start.

If you prefer for some reason to leave the master settings in place, add `skip-slave-start` to your `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` and the settings will then be ignored on start-up.

Comment: Had this problem, thanks for the solution! (I was replicating to a slave and wanted to do a permanent switch-over, and followed the MySQL doc which said I should do STOP SLAVE, RESET MASTER on the replica, which worked fine but every time I restart it tried to re-enable the slave, very frustrating :).